# How to reduce audio duration for AC3?

Tags: audio, sync, matroska

I have an MKV (an Italian version). I have extracted the H264 and the *unwanted* (Italian) AC3 audio. Now, I'd like to remux it with an English audio track (I have).

The problem is, the English track is quite long (around 1 hr. 50 mins or so...) while the H264 track is 4 mins behind. Is there a way I can reduce the duration of the audio (by some approximation) so that I can resync with the track and mux it into MKV container?

---

Actually, the audio delay at different positions made me suspect that the rate of AC3 track is quite fast (relative to the H264 track). And now, with mkvmerge, I changed the FPS to the default `24000/1001p` and finally, it synced with the audio. Now, it's playing perfect...

Comment: You extracted the audio *from* an MKV already, so why would you just ignore that?  Have a look at the delay for that track in the original MKV file, and set the appropriate value when you're remuxing (yes, MKV has this built-in, which is why the tracks were unequal length but played back fine to begin with).

Comment: @Breakthrough: You seem to be suggesting that the MKV contained *both* audio tracks, whereas nothing in the question suggests that's the case. Also see Bon Gart's answer below which covers the possibilities, given the English track came from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *where* exactly is that extra length?  Is it in the beginning?  Is it at the end?  Is it in some portion of the movie that is different?  You know... does the English version of the film have a 4 minute scene that the Italian version doesn't?  Or, are there multiple different scenes between them (for example... the differences in all the releases of Macross Plus).

Unfortunately, you really can't just chop those 4 minutes off one end or another, and expect the audio to sync up.  What you are most likely going to have to do, is take an editor, examine the audio with the video, find where the differences are, and then decide.  If it is an extra scene, then you will have to edit that portion of the audio out.  If it is just some kind of speed difference (the audio track has been slowed), you may be able to resync it.

[This is a link](http://www.videohelp.com/search?q=resync%20audio%20in%20mkv) to a search at Videohelp.com which is a site that WILL become your friend in this endeavor.  There you will be introduced to a variety of tools to do ALL of these kinds of things (edit the audio track, replace the track in the MKV, resync the track, etc.)  Read through a few of the threads in the search, and grab some of the tools.  The site also provides multiple tutorials in how to use the tools that they suggest.

Comment: Truly speaking, all my extractors & muxers are actually from that site. I watched the video somewhat (not completely). And, gone crazy by the long duration. So, I thought the bitrate of audio *might* have been increased or something like that. Okay, I'll definitely try listening to both *carefully* ;-)

Comment: Not just extra scenes, there's also the possibility that the audio and video tracks came from NTSC/PAL copies or vice versa, which would also cause a sync issue.

Comment: @Karan Absolutely.  My impression from the question is that the English audio did not come from the MKV container, but from a different source, which is why my answer is phrased as such.  If the original was PAL, and the English was NTSC, that would support your hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, a slight change in the FPS solved it. Have a look at my revision Bon. If you can address it, I'll be happy to accept your answer ;-)

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ actually, since you discovered what the actual problem and solution was, you should post that as an answer yourself.  Answering your own questions is allowed here.  Just detail how you used MKVMerge to do it, as well as where you can download it from.

Comment: @BonGart: I know. Thanks. But, I don't think I have sufficient knowledge in expressing an answer (I doubt it) to my question (especially in computing). That's why I thought you can answer it. BTW, mkvmerge was found in the toolnix package in the same website and the GUI version is somewhat easy to modify ;-)